# Making ppp connection over 3G modem as stable as possible

Tags: angstrom, pppd

I am using portuxG20 platform under Angstrom linux. The device collects data and sends it to the server via #g network using 3G modem. In the pppd log i have found following:

```
chat:  Aug 05 20:05:23 CONNECT
Serial connection established.
using channel 28
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB_utps_modem
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xb3dc4361> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x6c <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x14ad140> <pcomp> <accomp>]
No auth is possible
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x6c <auth chap MD5>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xb3dc4361> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x6d <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x14ad140> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x6d <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x14ad140> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x6e magic=0x14ad140]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns3 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns3 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x2 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns3 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns3 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x36]
sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x36 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x3 <compress VJ 0f 01>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x4 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns3 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x37]
sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x37]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x4 <addr 10.21.23.245> <ms-dns1 10.74.210.210> <ms-dns3 10.74.210.211>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x5 <addr 10.21.23.245> <ms-dns1 10.74.210.210> <ms-dns3 10.74.210.211>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x5 <addr 10.21.23.245> <ms-dns1 10.74.210.210> <ms-dns3 10.74.210.211>]
Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
local  IP address 10.21.23.245
remote IP address 10.64.64.64
primary   DNS address 10.74.210.210
secondary DNS address 10.74.210.211
Script /etc/ppp/ip-up started (pid 8441)
Script /etc/ppp/ip-up finished (pid 8441), status = 0x0
sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15>]
rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x6f 80 fd 01 01 00 0c 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78 00]
Connect script failed
Terminating on signal 15
Modem hangup
Connection terminated.
Connect script failed
Terminating on signal 15
Modem hangup
Connection terminated.
Connect script failed
Terminating on signal 15
Modem hangup
.
.
.
```

After some time the connection is established. How can I find out why is this happening and what was the cause of the problem?

My provider script looks like this:

```
debug
logfile /home/logs/pppd.log
user "vodafone"
connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /home/scripts/chatscripts/pap"
/dev/ttyUSB_utps_modem
115200
noipdefault
usepeerdns
defaultroute
persist
noauth
```

I have a script that is checking whether ping to ntdp server works, and if not it kills pppd and makes a new call (I am not sure if this is the correct way for something like that and maybe that makes problem):

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/scripts/isconnected
TTY="$(cat /home/scripts/.gsm_plugged)"
SERVER="0.de.pool.ntp.org"

sed s/isconnected=[0-9]/isconnected=0/ -i /home/scripts/isconnected

while [ -c $TTY ]
do
sleep 30
ping -c 10 $SERVER > /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
            echo "ping failed"
            echo "restarting"
            pkill pppd
            sleep 2
            /usr/sbin/pppd call provider
            sleep 10
            ntpdate -s 0.de.pool.ntp.org
            sed s/isconnected=[0-9]/isconnected=0/ -i /home/scripts/isconnected
    else
            sed s/isconnected=[0-9]/isconnected=1/ -i /home/scripts/isconnected
    fi
done
```

Comment: At first glance it looks OK.  Note that your PPP connection can not be more stable than the 3G connection.

Comment: Ok, but is my pinging and killing on fail in clash with persist option of the pppd itself. Because, we have some kind of test and the small device had holes in connection while on my phone the connection was always good, that's why I want to make everything i possibly could in order to prevent all problems except 3G network breakdown.

Comment: I assumed you already tried that configuration and it failed to reconnect or it was too slow.  If that's really the case, your monitoring script is a good idea.  I've used similar script in the past to overcome intermittent connection problems.  The OS will not be able to tell you why the link froze or got disconnected in any case, but it is likely due to an underlying network stability issue on the 3G network.  Using an external antenna could be a good idea if possible.

Comment: Ok, but after first failure, if the 3G network was problem, I would expect to find in the log file something like no 3G signal or something similar.

Comment: My point was actually related to the fact that your computer does not know the 3G connection, it only knows it as a network interface and the 3G connection status is only known from within the adapter.